# Java - Getting the path to all users in windows

Tags: java, path, shortcut

I am working on writing into the shortcut directory of all users, and I have it working I believe but the way I am getting the paths don't seem right. And I don't know if it is the correct way of checking if the all users path is there or if there is a better way. This is suppose to be able to work on windows xp - windows 8. and from windows server 2000 - 2012. 
Here is the code:

```
        int pathOne = 0;
        int pathTwo = 0;
        String allUserPath = "";

        File sourceOne = new File("C:\\ProgramData\\Microsoft\\Windows\\Start Menu\\");  
        if (sourceOne.exists())
        {
            pathOne = 1;
        }

        File sourceTwo  = new File("C:\\Documents and Settings\\All Users\\Start Menu\\");
        if (sourceTwo.exists())
        {
            pathTwo = 1;
        }

        if (pathOne == 1 && pathTwo == 0)
        {
        allUserPath = "C:\\ProgramData\\Microsoft\\Windows\\Start Menu\\Programs";
        }

        if (pathTwo == 1 && pathOne== 0)
        {
        allUserPath = "C:\\Documents and Settings\\All Users\\Start Menu\\Programs";
        }
```

Update: Doing some research I found out that you can execute command line querys.

```
 public static final String REG_QRY_CMD="reg query ";
 public static final String SHORT_CUT_REG_KEY="HKCU\\Software\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Explorer\\Shell Folders";

String str = REG_QRY_CMD+"\""+
            SHORT_CUT_REG_KEY+"\""+ " /v " + "\""+ "Programs" +"\"";
```

Now this will get me up to the current user's program folder:
Example "C:\Documents and Settings\al\Start Menu\Programs" or "E:\Documents and Settings\meg\Start Menu\Programs" Is there a way I can slice this? to atleast get the "?:\Documents and Settings\"? That way I can atleast add it into all users instead of just the current user. This way it will be less guess work and slightly better. Thank you

Comment: *"Getting the path to all users in windows"*  What will the app. do for all users of OS X & *nix?

Comment: This is just for adding the shortcut's to all users versus just the current user.

Comment: Are you trying to write an installer? Please don't do that (particularly not if you're writing it in Java when it's specific for Windows!). There are **plenty** of installers out there and some of them are even free. Windows has *specific* APIs for finding that path and doing anything other than asking Windows where that path is is pure guesswork and will break horribly on new versions, different language versions of Windows, custom installs with modified paths and all other kinds of (valid) installations.

Comment: Yeah I am trying to write it on an installer, but I have to write it up myself, I dont know of a better way of doing it other then this. Which is why I am asking.I can't use any other installers other then what I have access to .

Comment: The **best** way is: "use an existing, well-tested installer creation tool". Other than that: find and call the native API that Windows provides to query that kind of information (sorry, I don't know the specific API, I don't do Win32 programming).

Comment: I can't use the best way sadly only the way they want me to do it. So I have to just call the native API to get that information?

Comment: Sometimes, the best course of action is to go to the management which is telling you this is how they want to do it this way and inform them (politely) that they are doing it in a far more difficult way then they need to. Good management will appreciate that.

Answer (score 0):

On systems in other languages you need more.

One strategy is using the info from the current user to fetch all-users directories.

System info can be got from:

```
System.getProperties().list(System.out);
```

Unfortunately only `System.getProperty("user.home")` might be of interest. With that directory you might construe the all-users directory.

The same would hold for java.awt.Desktop and the JDIC library might be worth looking into.

Comment: Trying to use what you have with the `System.getProperties().list(System.out);` and `System.getProperty("user.home")`  And while it does give the user info it doesn't give me much to go with.

Answer (score -1):

You should use an installer in the first place, but you could use something from that code:

```
    FileSystemView fsv = FileSystemView.getFileSystemView();
    File[] roots = fsv.getRoots();
    for (int i = 0; i < roots.length; i++)
    {
     System.out.println("Root => " + roots[i]);
    }
```

This will return a list of root directories.

In addition, you could use fsv.getHomeDirectory()) and this should return for instance "C:\Documents and Settings\daniel\Desktop" on Windows.

Nevertheless, you should avoid using a "C:" as a system drive apriori.

Comment: I have something similar using a Cmd query to search for programs and the problem i am getting with that is that It installs on the current user versus all users which is what I am trying to get.